# Member Variable from one class to another

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005

I am unable to resolve this error.

Source1.h// it has Class CSystem

```
               static PvGenInteger *lIPAddressParam;
```

Source2.cpp  //it has Class MGUI

```
             CSystem :: lIPAddressParam ;
             PvInt64 lIPAddress = 0;
         lIPAddressParam->GetValue( lIPAddress );
```

This gives the error:

> Undeclared lIPAddressParam.

If i use this code line:

```
lIPAddressParam->GetValue( lIPAddress );
```

in a single source file, it works, but not in this case. Kindly guide. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

// include in .cpp, static variables should be initialized in a compile time

```
PvGenInteger* CSystem ::lIPAddressParam;
```

**issue is due to you ommited type of static variable** in .cpp file;
specify it and all should be fine

Comment: Are you sure about the default init of static pointers being a `nullptr` value?

Comment: it gives me another error : Definition or redeclaration not allowed in the current scope C2665

Comment: @leemes  no I am not, then I better delete that info, and check it

Comment: @Nabeel in .cpp no static keyword should be in front of type, did you ommit it?

Comment: static PvGenInteger * lIPAddressParam; THis I declared in the header file of Class CSystem.  and this i declared in cpp file of Class MGUI PvGenInteger * CSystem ::lIPAddressParam;  But error is the redeclaration of member function is not allowed

Comment: @Nabeel lIPAddressParam->GetValue( lIPAddress ); - must have a body in .cpp file (should be defined) if you declare it in header.